# Filter by words and copy to new place

Tags: excel, vba

I filter by words on "DATA" sheet from the word on "Check sector" sheet, then I copy the result to "Check sector" A5 cell.

```vb
Sub Macro12()
'
' Macro12 Macro
'

'
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1000").AutoFilter Field := 4, Criteria1 := Array(,,) _
        , Operator := xlFilterValues
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Check SECTOR").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

How can I fix

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1000").AutoFilter Field := 4, Criteria1 := Array(,,) _
    , Operator := xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the word from "Check SECTOR", you can **store the value in a variable & call it while filtering** for parameter Criteria1.

```vb
Sub Macro12()

    Dim val As String
    val = Sheets("Check SECTOR").Range("B3").Value
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=val _
        , Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Check SECTOR").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```